# Aliases in calculations for MySQL

Tags: mysql, alias, computed-column

I am in the process to move a really small database from Access to MySQL and I have some queries to translate.

I have this really simple query (in Access db):

```sql
SELECT InvoiceNumber,
       Field1 + Field2 AS CalcField1,
       Field3 + Field4 AS CalcField2,
       (CalcField1 - CalcField2) / CalcField2 AS Percentage ;
```

This does not work in MySQL, because it does not allow column aliases in formulas. I learnt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077475/using-an-alias-in-sql-calculations) that the solution is to wrap the alias with a `(SELECT alias)`. That works, but the result is really ugly and becomes unreadable. In my case it is:

```
((SELECT ((SELECT CalcField1) - (SELECT CalcField2))) / (SELECT CalcField2)) AS Percentage
```

In the former case I can understand immediately the expression, in the latter I cannot.

My question is: is there an alternative way to use aliases in MySQL formulas that have a better readability?

Comment: I have to use the resulting SQL code it in a view.

Answer (score 1):

It's more readable if you use a derived table. No need for 4 `SELECT` clauses, just 2. Plus, it's proper SQL, not some fancy feature that MySQL or Access has added:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber,
       CalcField1,
       CalcField2,
       (CalcField1 - CalcField2) / CalcField2 AS Percentage 
FROM 
    ( SELECT InvoiceNumber,
             Field1 + Field2 AS CalcField1,
             Field3 + Field4 AS CalcField2
      FROM ...
    ) AS x ;
```

The other option, is not to use a derived table at all but double the calculated expressions:

```
SELECT InvoiceNumber,
       Field1 + Field2 AS CalcField1,
       Field3 + Field4 AS CalcField2,
       ((Field1 + Field2) - (Field3 + Field4)) / (Field3 + Field4) 
         AS Percentage 
FROM ... ;
```

Comment: The first option works if I use it like a query, if I try to create a view with the very same query, I get an error: `Error 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause SQL Statement`

Comment: Yes, you can't have a view with a derived table. That's a known limitation of mysql. But that was not in your question (that you want a view).

Comment: Yes, it was not in my question: I am a newbie with MySQL and I took for granted that whatever worked as a query It would have worked as a view.